# Java Style Lambda Expressions for Anonymous Classes in Scala

Tags: java, scala, lambda

In the [Lambda Expressions Java Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html), [approach 5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html#approach5) improves upon [approach 4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html#approach4) by converting the anonymous class instantiation

```
new CheckPerson() {
    public boolean test(Person p) {
        return p.getGender() == Person.Sex.MALE
            && p.getAge() >= 18
            && p.getAge() <= 25;
    }
}
```

to

```
(Person p) -> p.getGender() == Person.Sex.MALE
    && p.getAge() >= 18
    && p.getAge() <= 25
```

Is there an equivalent in Scala so that I can avoid doing:

```
new CheckPerson {
    def test(p: Person): Boolean = {
        p.getGender == Person.Sex.MALE
            && p.getAge >= 18
            && p.getAge <= 25
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @JoeK that was the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
val x: CheckPerson = (p: Person) => p.getGender == Person.Sex.MALE &&
                                    p.getAge >= 18 &&
                                    p.getAge <= 25
```